# How to store an output of array from a loop without printing it

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a programming problem on a site. It says to check if the word is Palindrome. If it is, then print "Yes" or if it isn't then "No". I've done almost but there's a problem. I can't store the output of the reversed string of an array.

I tried in many ways to do. but I have failed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int i,len;
    char mainword[100], reverseword[100];

    scanf("%s",mainword);

    len = strlen(mainword);

    strcpy(reverseword,mainword);

    for(i=len; i>=0; i--){
        printf("%c",reverseword[i]);
              // I just need here to save the output without printing it. So, that later I can compare it. 

    }

    if(strcmp(reverseword,mainword)==0){
        printf("\nYes");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo");
    }
}
```

I expect that it will store the string value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){

    int i,len,j=0;
    char mainword[100], reverseword[100];

    scanf("%s",mainword);

    len = strlen(mainword);

    for(i=len; i>=0; i--){
        reverseword[j] = mainword[i-1];
        j++;
    }

    reverseword[j] = '\0';

    if(strcmp(reverseword,mainword)==0){
        printf("\nYes");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot null termination

Comment: @sakibkhandaker C strings are terminated by a null byte. Your C text book should clarify the issue. If you don't have a book now would be a good time to get one!

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
for(i=len; i>=0; i--){
    printf("%c",reverseword[i]);
          // I just need here to save the output without printing it. So, that later I can compare it. 

}
```

you'd better use just this:

```
for( i=0; i<len; i++) {
    reverseword[i] = mainword[len-i-1];
}
```

And it will magically work.

Comment: Where is the null termination

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `strcpy(reverseword,mainword);` takes care of that

Comment: So now you're copying the string only to have the terminator in the correct place...

Comment: @SakibKhandaker if you like the solution, please don't forget to accept and/or upvote =)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't, please, contact the OP re: design of his code, it's not of my concern.